# Разница между synchronized-блоками и synchronized-методами

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть ли между ними разница, или они эквивалентны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При синхронизации метода выполняется *эффективная* синхронизация по самому объекту. Если метод статический, синхронизация выполняется по классу объекта. Следующие два блока кода работают схожим образом:

```java
public synchronized int getCount() {
    // ...
}
```

Это то же самое, как если бы вы написали:

```java
public int getCount() {
    synchronized(this) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Если нужно контролировать синхронизацию по определенному объекту, или нужно синхронизировать только часть метода, тогда можно использовать блок `synchronized`. Если ключевое слово `synchronized` указано в сигнатуре метода, тогда синхронизируется весь метод или класс.

---

См. [Why is synchronized block better than synchronized method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906578/11141611)